# Where can find the docker image for building kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to build kubernetes locally. There are so many related go package. I think I should make a docker image for building kubernetes. Firstly, I want to know is there anyone have create the docker image for building kubernetes?.

Comment: What's are you asking and what have you tried already?

Comment: I want to build the kubernetes in the docker container. By this way, I must have the image first. So I want to know whether someone build kubernets in  docker container.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet from the [Github README](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes#building-kubernetes-for-the-impatient) might help you:

> ### Building Kubernetes for the impatient
>
> If you want to build Kubernetes right away there are two options:
>
> You have a working Go environment.

```
$ go get -d k8s.io/kubernetes
$ cd $GOPATH/src/k8s.io/kubernetes
$ make
```

> You have a working Docker environment.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
$ cd kubernetes
$ make quick-release
```

Comment: In the way, I need to go get all the related packages.